# How are intermediate containers formed?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I would like to understand the execution steps involved in building Docker Images using Dockerfile. Couple of questions I have listed down below. Please help me in understanding the build process.

## Dockerfile content

```
#from base image
FROM ubuntu:14.04
#author name
MAINTAINER RAGHU
#commands to run in the container
RUN echo "hello Raghu"
RUN sleep 10
RUN echo "TASK COMPLETED"
```

Command used to build the image: `docker build -t raghavendar/hands-on:2.0 .`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 20.04 MB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
---> b1719e1db756
Step 2 : MAINTAINER RAGHU
---> Running in 532ed79e6d55
---> ea6184bb8ef5
Removing intermediate container 532ed79e6d55
Step 3 : RUN echo "hello Raghu"
---> Running in da327c9b871a
hello Raghu
---> f02ff92252e2
Removing intermediate container da327c9b871a
Step 4 : RUN sleep 10
---> Running in aa58dea59595
---> fe9e9648e969
Removing intermediate container aa58dea59595
Step 5 : RUN echo "TASK COMPLETED"
---> Running in 612adda45c52
TASK COMPLETED
---> 86c73954ea96
Removing intermediate container 612adda45c52
Successfully built 86c73954ea96
```

In step 2 :

```
Step 2 : MAINTAINER RAGHU
    ---> Running in 532ed79e6d55
```

Question 1 : it indicates that it is running in the container with id -  532ed79e6d55, but with what Docker image is this container formed ?

```
---> ea6184bb8ef5
```

Question 2 : what is this id? Is it an image or container ?

```
Removing intermediate container 532ed79e6d55
```

Question 3 : Is the final image formed with multiple layers saved from intermediate containers?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, Docker images are layered. When you build a new image, Docker does this for each instruction (`RUN`, `COPY` etc.) in your Dockerfile:

1. create a temporary container from the previous image layer (or the base `FROM` image for the first command;
2. run the Dockerfile instruction in the temporary "intermediate" container;
3. save the temporary container as a new image layer.

The final image layer is tagged with whatever you name the image - this will be clear if you run `docker history raghavendar/hands-on:2.0`, you'll see each layer and an abbreviation of the instruction that created it.

Your specific queries:

1) `532` is a temporary container created from image ID `b17`, which is your `FROM` image, `ubuntu:14.04`.

2) `ea6` is the image layer created as the output of the instruction, i.e. from saving intermediate container `532`.

3) yes. Docker calls this the [Union File System](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/#/union-file-systems) and it's the main reason why images are so efficient.