# Where execute RUN command from Dockerfile, Host or Intermediate container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let say this is an example of a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER Kimbro Staken version: 0.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Here is my question: Do I run `RUN apt-get update` on the host PC or create an intermediate container and run on that and then commit it.

Answer (score 2):

It will create intermediate container, run all those commands specified using RUN and then commit it.

Comment: Please provide relevant references.

Comment: check `docker history myimage` and compare with the output of `docker build -t myimage .`

Comment: To understand images and containers , go through at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: Also go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705085/docker-how-are-intermediate-containers-formed