# Building Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Conatiner ID while building dockerfile.

I am building my own dockerfile. While building dockerfile using **docker build .** command I saw that it executes every command that was written in dockerfile. But while executing it displays a message **Running in some container ID** for every command written in dockerfile and also the ID changes for every command.
Are the containers changing for each and every command or the ID of same container changes as it also gets stop after every command execution

See the attached image and the highlighted text.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker : How are intermediate containers formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705085/docker-how-are-intermediate-containers-formed)

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroBellanda for giving the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Docker more or less acts like it runs `docker run` and `docker commit` for each line in the Dockerfile.  Containers never get reused; each line is a new container.

The other corollary to this is that the line after `Removing intermediate container ...` is a valid image ID, so one useful way to debug a build is to `docker run a15a9b` plugging in one of those intermediate image IDs.

Comment: That solved my issue that each time a new container is launched. Thank you sir.